# Hashmap cannot remove the value correctlly in java

Tags: java, hashmap

I hava input csv file, I will read the csv file into `Hashmap<String List<String>>`, The key would be (date, 139805, 68874 etc...), the value would the row (2 - 9) as a `List<Sting>` for each key. This is the input file:

[image]

After this I will filter the date, I have a `startTime` and `endTime` as filter, I will loop through the date column and check the date one by one to see if this date is in the range, and store the index of the date of the which is out of the range, into a `List<Integer>`. Then I will loop through all values of the Hashmap and remove the values using the index. I am not sure if I explain this clearly. The result is that the will not be removed correctly.

```
private void filterDate(Map<String, List<String>> csvMap, Date startTime,
        SimpleDateFormat sdf) throws ParseException {
    Date newEndTime = SetDate.add(startTime, Calendar.DATE, 21);
    System.out.println("start Time:" + sdf.format(startTime)
        + " end Time: " + sdf.format(newEndTime));

    List<Integer> index = CUtil.makeList();
    List<String> dates = csvMap.get("date");

    for(int i = 0; i < dates.size(); i ++) {
        Date currentDate = sdf.parse(dates.get(i));
        if (currentDate.before(startTime) || currentDate.after(newEndTime)) {
            System.out.println("remove: " + sdf.format(currentDate));
            index.add(i);
        }
    }

    for(int i = index.size() - 1; i > -1; i --) {
        for(List<String> values : csvMap.values()) {
            values.remove(i);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("left: date" + csvMap.get("date"));
}
```

Output:

```
start Time:2017-01-15 end Time: 2017-02-05
remove: 2017-01-08
remove: 2017-02-12
remove: 2017-02-19
remove: 2017-02-26
left: date[2017-02-05, 2017-02-12, 2017-02-19, 2017-02-26]
```

The date between **2017-01-15** and **2017-02-05** should be removed, but was not removed. That is weird.

Comment: Huh? Why are you manipulating the map view instead of using the map-based methods?

Comment: Note that the `Date` class is **legacy**. Use the classes inside the `java.time` package instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The Date is actually String, if you read carefully, the String will be converted to date when I compare the dates.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell, but it seems like it's working as designed? You're checking for before or after with your if statement

```
if (currentDate.before(startTime) || currentDate.after(newEndTime)) {
```

Since 2017-02-05 is equal to a date you're checking, it won't be removed. Maybe try this

```
if (currentDate.before(startTime) || currentDate.equals(startTime)
    || currentDate.after(newEndTime) || currentDate.equals(newEndTime)) {
```

*leaving the code above, as I still think it could help your situation*

EDIT: Try changing this section of code

```
for(int i = 0; i < dates.size(); i ++) {
    Date currentDate = sdf.parse(dates.get(i));
    if (currentDate.before(startTime) || currentDate.after(newEndTime)) {
        System.out.println("remove: " + sdf.format(currentDate));
        index.add(i);
    }
}

for(int i = index.size() - 1; i > -1; i --) {
    for(List<String> values : csvMap.values()) {
        values.remove(i);
    }
}
```

to this

```
for(int i = 0; i < dates.size(); i ++) {
    Date currentDate = sdf.parse(dates.get(i));
    if (currentDate.before(startTime) || currentDate.after(newEndTime)) {
        System.out.println("remove: " + sdf.format(currentDate));
        csvMap.values.remove(i);
    }
}
```

We're skipping the extra step of adding indexes into a new array and iterating through that, and also we're now deleting the values from your actual csvMap, instead of a newly created values List (which is then never used).

Comment: The problem is not about the startTime and endTime, the problem is that some date has been removed, but the hashmap still have it in the List<String> under the key "date".

Comment: Yeah, I'm fairly certain the problem lies in your for statement. You're creating a List of strings called values, and that's what you're removing the value from, not the original csvMap. So when you're outputting the value of csvMap, nothing has changed. I'll try to update my original answer to reflect this

Comment: Thank you very much, This key problem is that I was using "i" from for(int i = index.size() - 1; i > -1; i --) {
    for(List<String> values : csvMap.values()) {
        values.remove(i);
    }
} I should use values.remove(index.get(i).intValue);I tried the way you are  saying, it will show me the same result. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

I know where is wrong....

```
 for(int i = index.size() - 1; i > -1; i --) {
    for(List<String> values : csvMap.values()) {
        values.remove(i);
    }
}
```

I need to use `values.remove(index.get(i).intValue());`